# How to set permissions for a content type on the basis of some specific roles?

Tags: permissions, drupal-7, content-type, roles

Greetings.

I am working on a Drupal 7 site and wanted to discuss few permission related things where I am facing issues.

**I want the below mentioned permissions:**

1) I want to create a user lets say "Job posting manager" for example. Who can only create , edit job content type. No option to publish.

2) I want to create a another user lets say "Job admin manager" for example. Who can publish / edit the job along with create job.

So how can I set this type of permission for only specific content type and specific users?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the Content Type is named "job".

You'd need to create two Roles:

- Job Posting Manager
- Job Admin Manager

You can create these two roles by visiting admin/people/permissions/roles (bottom of the page)

Once the two roles are created, you should create two different users and assign them the proper role:

- User1 -> Assign the role "Job Posting Manager"
- User2 -> Assign the role "Job Admin Manager"

As a last step, you need to assign the proper permission to the newly created roles:

- Visit: admin/people/permissions
- Filter for "node" section and assign the permissions as you desire.

For a more detail workflow solution, take a look at Workbench and its submodules like Workbench Moderation.

Comment: Hi Condor, Thanks for your suggestion. One thing i want to confirm that we have installed the "Workbench" module and set the permission for user. But I want to give link to one user who can add the job and want to show a page where another user can see the added jobs. How we can pass the link to both users for related work ?